# ClickOnce application is signed, certs are in appropriate user store, but still says "Unknown Publisher"

Tags: clickonce, code-signing

I have an Office Add-In that I've deployed many times before. Here is the sequence I go through:

1. I get out my code signing certificate from a trusted CA (I actually have 2 from different CAs and both cause the same problem).
2. I put that in my Personal store so I can use it.
3. I export the public key to a .cer file.
4. I add that public key to the Trusted Publisher store.
5. I add the certificate above that one to the Intermediate store.
6. I add the root certificate to the Trusted Root CA store.
7. If installing from a network drive, I add it to the Intranet Sites list under IE > Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet > Sites > Advanced. In this case, I'm installing from a local drive.

Currently I'm using the user-level store, but for real deployment I put it in the machine-level store. AFAIK it doesn't really matter which store I use.

Usually, this results in a prompt-less, automatic installation. However, I switched machines and now I am getting prompted with an "Unknown Publisher" and a yellow warning icon.

[image: Prompt to install with "Unknown Publisher"]

It shouldn't be failing to check the CRL, I tried using the issuer's tools, and it says the cert is fine, and it happens even if CRL checks are turned off.

I dug through a lot of StackOverflow questions, and some google results too. Pretty much every question about this is a basic failure to adhere to the steps I listed above. I also turned on ClickOnce logging but it doesn't say anything about the publisher.

What else could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This was apparently due to using an old version of mage.exe that I had kept around for convenience's sake. Using a newer one, e.g. from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin, made it go away. Probably due to the signing algorithm used.

e: No, it was something else, and I still am not entirely sure what it was. There was some strange interaction with having CRL checks enabled/disabled.